# How can I create an audio file with an audio blob?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, mediarecorder

Sorry for my English.
I need to create an audio file with an audio blob.I create the audio file but it's crash and I don't know why, I THINK it's because the enconding was wrong, I tried some many ways to do that but nothing worked.
Here is my FrontEnd code:

```
mediaRecorder.onstop=() =>{
      const blob = new Blob(partesAudio,{type:'audio/ogg; code=opus'})
      const reader = new window.FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)


      reader.onloadend= async () =>{

      var resultado= await  fetch('http://localhost:3000/fala/',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              fala:reader.result //'frase8.wav'
            }),
          });...
```

Here is my BackEnd code:

```
app.post('/fala/', async(req, res) => {
  fs.writeFileSync('something.ogg', (req.body.fala));
 });
```

I tried to encode to base64 but, it isn't worked so I back the code.

Only to compare.

[A generate file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRso7.png).
[Random File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyKPQ.png).

Comment: try just sending the actual file instead of trying to base64 encoding it, might be hitting a memory issue if the file is very large. Also note your backend isnt decoding the base64 string back to binary data before writing to your file

Comment: I tried decoding in base64 in backend but I removed because not worked

Comment: fs.writeFileSync('something.ogg', Buffer.from(req.body.fala,'base64'));